# How many recessed lights does my kitchen need?

Tags: recessed-lighting

I am remodeling a 12x12 kitchen and want to add recess lighting. How many 6 inch led can lights would I need to fill the space with light?

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based. While there are general guidelines for this sort of thing to be found, they're subjective and vary wildly with kitchen layout, personal preference, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of options depending on what the actual layout looks like and what sort of look you want, but you could [Follow The Ceiling Height Rule Of Thumb](https://www.pegasuslighting.com/lc-lighting-design/how-to-layout-recessed-lighting-in-4-easy-steps.html):

> To determine how far apart to space your recessed lights, divide the height of the ceiling by two. If a room has an 8 foot ceiling, you should space your recessed lights approximately 4 feet apart. If the ceiling is 10 feet, you'll want to put about 5 feet of space in between each fixture.